# ValueError: The number of observations cannot be determined on an empty distance matrix

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, emotion

[I have this code which finds the clusteFile "..//src/clusterFaces.py", line 143, in main
    Z = linkage(distances, method='complete')r face detection error in](https://github.com/DCGM/EmotionService/blob/master/src/clusterFaces.py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

passing empty matrix shows this exception. i resolved this error by passing value.